How to bulk upload and edit metadata of each file in NodeJS?
I'm trying to test something in my NodeJS app in Postman where I want to be able to upload files. Now, the uploading itself works fine and I can just pass bunch of files in the multipart/form-data:
 async upload(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> {
    try {
      const user = await req.getUser();
      const { isAdmin, orgId, type: fileType, isLogo, isIcon } = req.query;

      const name = user.fullName;
      const altText = req.query.altText as string;
      const isAdminBool = util.toBool(isAdmin as string | undefined);
      const isLogoBool = util.toBool(isLogo as string | undefined);
      const isIconBool = util.toBool(isIcon as string | undefined);
  
      // Resolve destination folder based on conditions
      const destFolder = isAdminBool
        ? 'files/admin'
        : orgId
        ? `files/organization/${orgId}`
        : `files/user/${user.id}`;
  
      // Get files from the request
      const files = req.files as Express.Multer.File[];
  
      // Create a list of promises to handle file uploads
      const promUploads = files.map(async (file) => {
        const origname = file.originalname;
        let filename = origname;
  
        // Rename filename for icons
        if (fileType === 'icon') {
          const ext = path.extname(origname);
          if (!origname.endsWith(`.ico${ext}`)) {
            filename = `${path.basename(origname, ext)}.ico${ext}`;
          }
        }
  
        await this.storageService.isExists({ ...file, originalname: filename }, user.azure_id);
  
        return this.storageService.copyAndUploadFile(file.path, {
          delete: true,
          renameFilepath: `${destFolder}/${filename}`,
          category: fileType as string | undefined,
          uploadedBy: `${user.firstname} ${user.lastname}`,
          isIcon: isIconBool,
          isLogo: isLogoBool,
          title: name,
          altText
        });
      });
  
      const result = await Promise.all(promUploads);
  
      res.jsonSuccess(result);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error uploading images:', error);
      res.jsonError({ message: 'Failed to upload images', error });
    }
  }

What I need to be able to do now is that I want to be able to edit the properties of each file as I upload them. So if I have 5 files being uploaded, I want to be able to edit the name, altText, isLogo and isIcon independently.
So suppose I have 5 images being uploaded at the same time. I'd like to be able to change the metadata etc of all those 5 images.
Any guidance or assistance on how I can do this?
